# Почему не отображаются картинки при запуске программы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вместо картинок пустое место. Дальше отображаются картинки стандартные которые уже были в этом проекте.

Но картинки отображаются при просмотре в Visual Studio.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте воспроизводящий пример.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте пути до папок с картинками. У вас exe компилируется в папке bin/debug/ или bin/release/ относительно основного проекта.
Варианты решения:

1. Добавить в пути к картинкам "../../ваш путь". Но это плохое решение. Когда соберёте installer, вам придётся пути переписывать и,
   скорей всего, не будет отображаться в студии
2. Перекинуть папку с картинками в директории, в которых собирается проект. Тоже решение так себе - при каждом изменении/добавлении
   картинок заново их закидывать
3. Добавить у папки с картинками в свойствах значение "Copy to output directory" как "Copy always" или "Copy if never". Это уже нормальное
   решение.
4. Добавлять все ваши файлы как ресурсы (я бы так делал).